# Gradle - custom task to execute all GenerateMavenPom tasks

Tags: maven, groovy, gradle

I want to write a Gradle task to share among all my subprojects. This task finds all other tasks inside the subproject where it is called that have type "GenerateMavenPom" and executes those tasks.

By doing this, my subprojects can define any Maven publications that they wish, and I can execute gradle with a single task like "gradle generateMavenPomFiles" to create the pom.xml without knowing the individual publication types in each subproject. Why? Because the Maven plugin creates publication tasks whose names depend on the publication type.

Inside my **subprojects** block in the root build.gradle file I have, passing **subproject** as the closure delegate:

```
task generateMavenPomFiles << {
    model {
        TaskCollection<GenerateMavenPom> pomTasks = subproject.tasks.matching { t -> t.TASK_TYPE.equals("GenerateMavenPom") }

        if (pomTasks != null) {
            pomTasks.each { pomTask -> pomTask.execute }
        }
    }
}
```

I have accessed the Maven publishing tasks inside the **model** block as according to the plugin doc:

> The “maven-publish” plugin leverages some experimental support for
>   late plugin configuration, and any GenerateMavenPom tasks will not be
>   constructed until the publishing extension is configured. The simplest
>   way to ensure that the publishing plugin is configured when you
>   attempt to access the GenerateMavenPom task is to place the access
>   inside a model block...

Inside my subprojects I have Maven publications defined like this:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenCustom(MavenPublication) {
            artifacts = someArtifactTask.archivePath
            groupId = someGroupId
            artifactId = someArtifactId
            version = someVersion
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, "gradle generateMavenPomFiles" doesn't work. The task executes on each subproject but I don't see the actual Maven POM tasks created by the plugin being invoked.

I'm fairly new to Gradle + Groovy, so perhaps I have misunderstood something, or my logic is just wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the following snippet:

```
task runAllGenerateMavenPomTasks {
    dependsOn tasks.withType(GenerateMavenPom)
}
```